# Intuition behind transversal intersection between manifolds

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, transversality

I am following the book "Differential Topology" by Allan Pollack and I am a little bit stuck with transversal intersection between manifolds. I understood the proofs presented in section 5 of such book but still I am not able to fully understan the intuition behind transversality. For example in page 31 the author presents the following figures:
[image]

My problem is that I do not know how to determine whether the intersection is transversal or not just from the picture. On the internet I found that if you take one of the manifolds, shake it a little bit and if the intersection is similar or the same then it is transversal. However, I do not know if this is the right approach.

Any thoughts about the intuition behind this property would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Since you are evidently going to post lots of questions as you work through this book, let me point out that the main author is in fact V. Guillemin. To answer your question, when the surfaces intersect tangentially, can their two tangent planes add up to give you $\Bbb R^3 = T_x\Bbb R^3$?